# How to upload video to Vimeo through android app using vimeo official library?

Tags: android, video, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I have created Vimeo Pro Account and also application registered with the Vimeo API. After registered application i got client identifier and client secret key and also generated Access Token.

For integrating Vimeo api in android, i have used https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java vimeo official library.

I have successfully authorize Client Credentials.

Please suggest me the way and steps to upload video on vimeo using it's official library.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This library does not yet support video uploads. We're working on it!

Comment: Is there any other way to upload video from android without using library?

Comment: We have detailed docs on the protocol here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos and upload logic in other languages listed here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries